# Inheriting a private constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Trying to allow `make_unique` on a class with private ctor I came into the following strange difference between two cases:

---

### Case 1 - empty ctor - *compiles*

```
class A {
    int _i;
    A(): _i(7) {}
public:
    template<typename... T>
    static std::unique_ptr<A> create(T&&... t) {
        struct enablePrivateCtor : public A {
            using A::A;
        };
        return std::make_unique<enablePrivateCtor>(std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }
    void doIt() const {
        std::cout << _i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = A::create();
    a->doIt();
}
```

**Output:**

```
7
```

---

### Case 2 - non-empty ctor - *doesn't compile*

```
class A {
    int _i;
    A(int i): _i(i) {} // <- change 1, ctor getting int
public:
    // no change here!
    template<typename... T>
    static std::unique_ptr<A> create(T&&... t) {
        struct enablePrivateCtor : public A {
            using A::A;
        };
        return std::make_unique<enablePrivateCtor>(std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }
    void doIt() const {
        std::cout << _i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = A::create(7); // <- change 2, sending 7
    a->doIt();
}
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
unique_ptr.h: error: calling a private constructor of class 'enablePrivateCtor'
```

---

**Why the 1st one - with the empty ctor - is OK, while the 2nd - the non-empty ctor - is not?**

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, and more of a tip to help you improve your question: We don't need to see the `A` class *twice*. Instead you could just have had the first example, but with a second line like `auto b = A::create(7);  // Does not compile` It's okay to not have to show the program running or its output, since the question is about the build error (I assume).

Comment: FYI: this idea is wrong. You can't use a derived class like this; your `create` function invokes UB. You should instead rely on a private "key" class instance, which is constructible only by people with access to `A`. Your constructors of A that you want to be "private" should take an instance of that class as a parameter. That way, those with access to `A` can create such an instance and pass it in.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The examples *are* different. In the second example, `A` takes a parameter to its private constructor.

Comment: The default c'tor isn't really inherited. It's the one that is auto-generated by the compiler.

Comment: @StoryTeller but it does print 7

Comment: @NicolBolas The OP could still make a single example, by using default arguments, or an overloaded constructor. It's a lot of duplication that really don't add more information.

Comment: Of course. The auto generated one is defined to default construct all subobjects. Accessibility is disregarded for that one special case.

Comment: BTW, do you want `A`'s constructors being private or protected ?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't see any UB myself. What UB do you see?

Comment: @MooingDuck: `enablePrivateCtor` is derived from `A`, but `A` has no virtual destructor. So destroying it from a base class pointer (which is what will happen when you convert it to `unique_ptr<A>` will yield UB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default constructor is never inherited. Therefore, the first `enablePrivateCtor` generates a default constructor, which calls the base class default constructor.

When you inherit a constructor (as in the second case), the new constructor has the *same access level* as the inherited one. So since `A::A(int)` is private, so too will be `enablePrivateCtor::enablePrivateCtor(int)`. So you won't be able to construct with it.

If you need to have a private constructor be able to be called indirectly (through `make_unique`/`emplace`/etc), then you need to use a private key type. Like this:

```
class A;

class A_key
{
  A_key() = default;
  A_key(int) {} //Prevent `A_key` from being an aggregate.

  friend class A;
};

class A {
    int _i;
public:
    A(int i, A_key): _i(i) {}

    // no change here!
    template<typename... T>
    static std::unique_ptr<A> create(T&&... t)
    {
        return std::make_unique<A>(std::forward<T>(t)..., A_key{});
    }

    void doIt() const {
        std::cout << _i << std::endl;
    }
};

...

auto ptr = A::create(7);
A a(7, A_key{}); //Does not compile, since you're not a friend.
```

`A_key` is publicly copyable, but it is not publicly default constructible. So non-private code can pass them around, but non-private code cannot create them.

Comment: Note to future readers: This inheritance of access modifiers is peculiar to constructors: "A using-declarator that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored."

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `enablePrivateCtor` automatically gets a default constructor (which *is* allowed to call `A::A`).

It doesn't automatically get an integer conversion constructor: add

```
enablePrivateCtor(int i) : A(i) {}
```

and see it work.

Comment: OP inherits constructor, and so expects to not have to write it.

Comment: I'm surprised too, but a quick check with g++7.2 shows it does. I posted the answer but am still checking whether that's correct or a compiler bug.

Comment: @Useless there has to be something more (a bug maybe...), because the derived should not be able to access the private ctor: https://godbolt.org/g/GUGTAE

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because the derived is local to one of A's methods...

Comment: ie, because _A local class inside a function (including member function) can access the same names that the enclosing function can access._

Comment: @Useless Yes, being a nested class does give it access to all protected and private members of the outer class.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted has undefined behavior.

In particular, you allocate an `enablePrivateCtor` then delete an `A`.

A better way than this is to use a key type.

```
class A {
  int _i;
  A(): _i(7) {}
  class construction_token_t {
    explicit construction_token_t(int) {}
    friend class A;
  };
  static auto ctor_token() { 
    return construction_token_t(0);
  }
public:
  template<class...Args>
  A( construction_token_t, Args&&...args ):A(std::forward<Args>(args)...){}

  template<typename... T>
  static std::unique_ptr<A> create(T&&... t) {
    return std::make_unique<A>(ctor_token(), std::forward<T>(t)...);
  }
  void doIt() const {
    std::cout << _i << std::endl;
  }
};
```

We create a token which can grant another class the right to access our private ctor.  The only one who can create this token is our class.

We then pass it to `make_unique`.

---

An alternative is to use the factory lambda pattern.

```
template<class F>
struct factory_lambda_t {
  F f;
  template<class T>
  operator T() const { return f(); }
};

template<class F>
factory_lambda_t<std::decay_t<F>>
factory( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

In C++14 this requires move/copy ctors to be public, but in C++17 it doesn't.

```
class A {
  int _i;
  A(): _i(7) {}
public:
  template<typename... T>
  static std::unique_ptr<A> create(T&&... t) {
    return std::make_unique<A>(factory([&]{
      return A(std::forward<T>(t)...);
    }));
  }
  void doIt() const {
    std::cout << _i << std::endl;
  }
};
```

which I think is pretty slick.

This may result in eliding constructors completely in some cases.  In others, a single move occurs.